# Angular template "try-with-resource"

Tags: angular

As you might be familiar, Java has feature of try-with-resource, that ensures, some resources are created within try context and closed afterwards:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for some equivalent in templates in Angular. My use case wold be following (in pseudo-template)

```
<ng-template WITH-RESOULRCE="getData() as data"
  <div *ngIf="data.someField">
    Yay Some field exist
  </div>
  <div>
    Other content non-dependent on data.someField but on data itself
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

So far I was using alternative by `*ngIf`-ing resource I want to work with:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="getData() as data"
  <div *ngIf="data.someField">
    Yay Some field exist
  </div>
  <div>
    Other content non-dependent on data.someField but on data itself
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

but this approach and conditional template displaying does not meets my needs anymore ans does not provide to connect any additional boolean logic to it (i.e. `*ngIf="getData() as data && flag === true"` is considered to be syntax error.

So, long story short: Is there a way, to create boundry-scoped template variable, that will refer to controller variable?

Comment: Without thinking too much about it, how about a pipe with an injected service? (the pipe would be your `try (resource) {}` and the injected service would be the resource)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngTemplate`, `ngTemplateOutlet` & `ngTemplateOutletContext` to solve your problem:

So this is your template, where you can pass data using `templateOutletContext`, here value is an object that will be passed (kind of template with a resource):

```
<ng-template let-value="value" #testTemplate"
  <div *ngIf="value.someField">
    Yay Some field exist
  </div>
  <div>
    Other content non-dependent on data.someField but on data itself
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

and then, we will render our template using ng-container and will pass the data:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="testTemplate" 
       [ngTemplateOutletContext] ="{value: {someField: '10'}}">
</ng-container>
```